# Printing the keys of array elements which are arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
 <?php
    $arr = array('submitted',
                 'region' => array('value 1','value2','value3'),
                 'sended',
                 'something' => array('value','value'));

  ?>
```

The question is how to check if an element is an array and print the corresponding key.

The output should be:

```
region  something
```

Comment: i dont understand what do you want exactly, please describe it better

Comment: i want to check if an element is an array in the main array and print the element name

Comment: question is clear enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $k=>$a) {
    if (is_array($a)) echo $k;
}
```